# How to sample with various sample size in R?

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to get a random sample from  a dataframe with different size.
example the first sample should only have 8 observations
2nd sample can have 10 observations
3rd can have 12 observations

df[sample(nrow(df),10 ), ]

this gives me a fixed 10 observations when I take a sample

In an ideal case, I have 100observations and these observations should be placed in 3 groups without replacement and each group can have any number of observations. example group 1 has 45 observations, group 2 has 20 observations and group 3 has 35 observations.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `df[sample(nrow(df), sample(5:10, 1)), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `replicate`:

```
times_to_sample = 5L
NN = nrow(df)
replicate(times_to_sample, df[sample(NN, sample(5:10, 1L)), ], simplify = FALSE)
```

This will return a `list` of length `times_to_sample`, the `i`th element of which will give you a `data.frame` with the result for the `i`th replication.

`simplify=FALSE` prevents `simplify2array` from mangling the results into a not-particularly-useful matrix.

You should also consider adding some robustness checks -- for example, you said you want between 5 and 10 rows, but in generalizing this to be from `a` to `b` rows, you'll want to ensure `a >= 1`, `b <= nrow(df)`.

If `times_to_sample` is going to be large, it'll be more efficient to get all of the samples from `5:10` up front instead:

```
idx = sample(5:10, times_to_sample, replace = TRUE)
lapply(idx, function(i) df[sample(NN, i), ])
```

A little less readable but surely more efficient than to repeatedly to `sample(5:10, 1)`, i.e. only one at a time (not leveraging vectorization)